# W2UI: Click and other events of content loaded inside panels are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, w2ui

I'm using [w2ui 1.5-rc1](http://w2ui.com/web/home) layout components.
Attaching an event handler to an element inside a panel won't trigger the action:

```html
<script>
    $(function() {
         $('#layout').w2layout({
            name: 'mainArea',
            panels: [
                { type: 'left', size: 200, resizable: true, style: panels, content: 'left' },
                { type: 'main', style: main, content: 'main' }
            ]
        });
        w2ui['mainArea'].content('main', $("#list-panel").html());

        $("#mylist li a").click(function() {
           alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
        });
   })
</script>
<div id="layout"></div>
<div id="list-panel" style="visibility: hidden" >
    <ul id="mylist" class="list-group">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="alert('This one will work')"><span>Adele</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Bella</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Carl</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Clicking on the items **Bella** or **Carl** will never trigger the alert. 
If I remove the w2ui layout then everything works.

```html
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#mylist li a").click(function() {
           alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
        });
    })
</script>
<div id="list-panel" >
    <ul id="mylist" class="list-group">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="alert('This one will work')"><span>Adele</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Bella</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Carl</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I noticed that the same happens when I try to add bootstrap components or any other content inside a panel. The click, change and other events on those components are never triggered.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by other users in w2ui github repository, attaching the events to the document element will work.

```
$(document).on("click", "#mylist li a", function() {
   alert( "Handler for .click() called" );
});
```